# SearchView with Toolbar inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I am using `SearchView` with `Toolbar` inside fragment and i want to register for `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` interface so that i can get callback when user perform search.

I am inflating the menu with `Toolbar` as (inside `onCreateView`):

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Inflating the menu this way does not call `onCreateOptionMenu` method and normally we register for the callback in that method as:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        mGoTodayMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_go_to_today);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search");
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: I wish i could know the reason of downvoting this question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not calling `onCreateOptionsMenu()` because you need to call  `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView()` of your fragment.

---

You can remove this code from `onCreateView()`

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return false;
    }
});
```

After doing all this. You can easily use your `onCreateOptionMenu()` implementation for the search view.

Hope it helps.
Cheers!